# How to continuously populate HTML textbox from curl API

Tags: javascript, java, html, api, curl

I have a HTML textbox which I would like to populate with data received from an API call using `curl` command.
The curl API that I'm using, continuously returns/livestreams data in the following format:

```
curl <api_endpoint>

data: value1
data: value2
data: value3
```

And I would like for livestream be displayed in the HTML textbox when a button is clicked.
My HTML, JS looks like this:

```
<html>
<textarea rows='14' id="value" placeholder="anything you want here"></textarea>
<button class="get_values" onclick="return get()">GET</button>
</html>

<script>

const getButton = document.querySelector('.get_values');

getButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  #fill the textbox from curl command livestream
});

</script>
```

How can I fill the textbox with data stream from a `curl <api_endpont>` command?
There is no need for a websocket, API that I'm using already streams/sends the data continuously in realtime, I just need to make a call and fill the textbox.

Comment: You need a server that supports streams like socket.io and a client in your front-end.

Comment: @jimmysumshugar No, my API already sends data continously, so there is no need for a websocket. I just need to make a call using curl and fill the textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just update the value by making a `GET` request, and make the function repeat itself at some specified interval. Also `onclick` on button already adds an event listener, thus the code would go something like this.

```html
<html>
<body>
<textarea rows='14' id="value" placeholder="anything you want here"></textarea>
<button class="get_values" onclick="startUpdate(event)">GET</button>

<script>
// to set an update interval at every 2 sec(2000ms)
function startUpdate(e) {
  // e. preventDefault();
  // calling instantly
  updateTextArea();
  // and setting interval
  window.setInterval(updateTextArea, 2000);
}

// defining global variable, to display dynamic update
window.counter = 1

function updateTextArea() {
  let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + window.counter; // test url
  // assuming data is json, if it is text use response.text()
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      let textArea = document.getElementById("value");
      // parsing the JSON value to string
      textArea.value = JSON.stringify(data);
    })
  window.counter = window.counter + 1; // increment counter
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** To pass event you should pass the keyword `event` in onclick function call.

Comment: I tried your code with this url (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/), but when I press the button nothing happens, could you please take a look?

Comment: I have edited it and added a snippet for convenience.